# OnClick change scene issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't get my button to change the scenes.
Trying to change scene when a UI button is clicked. I have a script called `SceneRemote.cs` that just does this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class SceneRemote : MonoBehaviour 
{

     public void Change(string scene)
     {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(scene);
     }
}
```

This script was then added to the Canvas holding the button, then I pulled in that Canvas into the `OnClick()` component where it is set up in the following structure:

`Runtime Only -> Canvas` and `SceneRemote.Change -> Scene1`
Note: Both scenes *have* been added to the build settings.

Comment: where is the event handler for the button click.. you need to wire that up..

Comment: I don't really understand that. what am missing

Comment: dude you're likely not PUTTING THE STRING in the button where it calls to "Change"

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 -- *CHECK* your canvas is intact: MUST have EventSystem, MUST usually be 'scale with screen size'

1 -- *CLICK* "+" on the drag area of the button

2 -- *DRAG* to the button (in your case drag the holder of SceneRemote)

3 -- *SELECT* the correct function ("Change" for you)

4 -- *ENTER* the argument if any (in your case there will be a text field where you will enter the scene name)

[image]

5 -- *LOG* add a `Debug.Log("yo... "+scene)` statement inside your routine Change.  Play, click button, *look at console*

6 -- *SCREENSHOT* the same as the one above and edit in to your question